# Oracle email send date some times are not correct

Tags: oracle, email, plsql, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have a production issue relate Oracle 11g email send date. The code is like below.

```
  procedure email(p_recip   in apex_application_global.vc_arr2,
                  p_subject in varchar2,
                  p_message in varchar2) is

    c                  utl_smtp.connection;
    msg                varchar2(4000);
    username           varchar2(100) := 'XXX';
    password           varchar2(100) := '123';
    l_encoded_username varchar2(200);
    l_encoded_password varchar2(200);
    l_recips           varchar2(2000);

    procedure send_header(name in varchar2, header in varchar2) as
    begin
      utl_smtp.write_data(c, name || ': ' || header || utl_tcp.crlf);
    end;
  begin
    --Open SMTP connection
    l_encoded_username := utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(utl_encode.base64_encode(utl_raw.cast_to_raw(username)));
    l_encoded_password := utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(utl_encode.base64_encode(utl_raw.cast_to_raw(password)));
    c                  := utl_smtp.open_connection('AAA.BBB.local', '25');
    utl_smtp.ehlo(c, 'AAA.BBB.local'); --DO NOT USE HELO
    utl_smtp.command(c, 'AUTH', 'LOGIN');
    utl_smtp.command(c, l_encoded_username);
    utl_smtp.command(c, l_encoded_password);
    utl_smtp.mail(c, 'XXX@YYY.on.ca');

    if ((p_recip is null) or p_recip.count = 0) then
      return;
    end if;

    for i in 1 .. p_recip.count loop
      utl_smtp.rcpt(c, p_recip(i));
      l_recips := l_recips || p_recip(i) || ','; --mark as Multiple receivers
    end loop;

    --now remove the trailing comma at the end of l_recips
    l_recips := substr(l_recips, 0, length(l_recips) - 1);

    utl_smtp.open_data(c);

    --prepare mail header
    utl_smtp.write_data(c, 'Date: ' ||
                         to_char(sysdate, 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') ||
                         utl_tcp.crlf);

    utl_smtp.write_data(c, 'To: ' || l_recips || utl_tcp.crlf);

    utl_smtp.write_data(c, 'From: ' ||
                         '"Company" <MMM@KKK.on.ca>' ||
                         utl_tcp.crlf);
    utl_smtp.write_data(c, 'Subject: ' || p_subject || utl_tcp.crlf ||
                         utl_tcp.crlf);

    --include the message body
    utl_smtp.write_data(c, msg);

    -- Write message body
    utl_smtp.write_data(c, p_message || utl_tcp.crlf);

    -- Clean up
    utl_smtp.close_data(c);
    utl_smtp.quit(c);

  exception
    when utl_smtp.transient_error or utl_smtp.permanent_error then
      begin
        utl_smtp.quit(c);
      exception
        when utl_smtp.transient_error or utl_smtp.permanent_error then
          null;
          -- When the SMTP server is down or unavailable, we don't have
        -- a connection to the server. The QUIT call will raise an
        -- exception that we can ignore.
      end;

      raise_application_error(-20000, 'Failed to send mail due to the following error: ' ||
                               sqlerrm);
  end;

------------------------------------------

Unfortunately, the date on received email "Sent:" some times are wrong.  
For example :
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: one is the date from your database - and one is the date from the email server...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The data format is specified in [RFC 822](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc0822.txt) (and four-digit years were added in [RFC1123](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1123.txt)). You're sending the date in a different format. It looks like this is sometimes being accepted, and sometimes not; and is giving the 'wrong' results when it is. The date in the folder view is the received date, not the sent date, so it doesn't really have any bearing - except that it lines up with the date in the message body as a useful cross-reference.

You're doing this:

```
utl_smtp.write_data(c, 'Date: ' ||
                     to_char(sysdate, 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') ||
                     utl_tcp.crlf);
```

So right now I'd get a value of `Date: 05-09-2014 17:43:28`. According to the RFCs that should be interpreted as `2014-09-05` (September 5th). You seem to be seeing that sometimes, but not always, suggesting that MTAs are handling that differently. Based on the three examples, that may depend on whether the 'wrong' date is valid. If I send a mail with that date is does appear in Outlook at `2014-09-05`; but if I change it to `05-23-2014 17:43:28` then it comes through with the correct date - presumably because the invalid date `2014-23-05` is silently rejected, and the MTA uses its current date instead. (Or the client does; that might be more likely in fact).

You seem to have a further twist in the second example as it shows `06/10/2013` instead of, as you might expect form the 'correct' dates, `06/11/2013`. I think that's because you're losing the time zone offset as well; in fact you aren't setting one, but you might still be crossing a date boundary when it's adjusted.

So format your date as the RFC expects:

```
utl_smtp.write_data(c, 'Date: ' ||
                     to_char(systimestamp, 'Dy DD Mon YYYY HH24:MI:SS TZH:TZM',
                         'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') ||
                     utl_tcp.crlf);
```

Which gives:

```
Date: Fri 09 May 2014 17:47:52 +01:00
```

in my BST time zone. Note you have to use `systimestamp` rather than `sysdate` to get the time zone information. And it has to be in English so I've added the optional third parameter to `to_char()` to ensure that is the case regardless of the session locale.

---

As @ShoeLace pints out in comments, the string above still doesn't quite match RFC 822, and it should probably be:

```
utl_smtp.write_data(c, 'Date: ' ||
                     to_char(systimestamp, 'Dy, DD Mon YYYY HH24:MI:SS TZHTZM',
                         'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') ||
                     utl_tcp.crlf);
```

Which now gives:

```
Date: Tue, 04 Aug 2015 10:09:31 +0100
```

Some servers may accept without the comma or with the colon, but better to be correct...

Comment: Thanks Alex provide the detailed solution!

Comment: @Matthew - no problem; I've just added a small change to make sure it's always sent in English, as that could potentially cause a problem too.

Comment: rfc0822 says ' ( ("+" / "-") 4DIGIT )        ; Local differential                                                 ;  hours+min. (HHMM)'  so I dont think there should be a colon in the timezone offset.. ?

Comment: and specifies there should be a comma after the day name..  so maybe something more like ```TO_CHAR(systimestamp, 'Dy "," DD Mon YYYY HH24:MI:SS TZHTZM','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH')```

Comment: @ShoeLace - good points; not sure now if I actually tested this at the time; and if I did some SMTP servers may be more forgiving than others. Thanks.

Comment: i would expect most servers to be reasonably lenient on punctuation..  but the original poster id have a problem with incorrect format.. so you never know i guess.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add some extra detail to the answer from @alex-poole.

The STMP date format is specified in section 5 of http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc0822.txt:

```
5.1.  SYNTAX

 date-time   =  [ day "," ] date time        ; dd mm yy
                                             ;  hh:mm:ss zzz

 day         =  "Mon"  / "Tue" /  "Wed"  / "Thu"
             /  "Fri"  / "Sat" /  "Sun"

 date        =  1*2DIGIT month 2DIGIT        ; day month year
                                             ;  e.g. 20 Jun 82

 month       =  "Jan"  /  "Feb" /  "Mar"  /  "Apr"
             /  "May"  /  "Jun" /  "Jul"  /  "Aug"
             /  "Sep"  /  "Oct" /  "Nov"  /  "Dec"

 time        =  hour zone                    ; ANSI and Military

 hour        =  2DIGIT ":" 2DIGIT [":" 2DIGIT]
                                             ; 00:00:00 - 23:59:59

 zone        =  "UT"  / "GMT"                ; Universal Time
                                             ; North American : UT
             /  "EST" / "EDT"                ;  Eastern:  - 5/ - 4
             /  "CST" / "CDT"                ;  Central:  - 6/ - 5
             /  "MST" / "MDT"                ;  Mountain: - 7/ - 6
             /  "PST" / "PDT"                ;  Pacific:  - 8/ - 7
             /  1ALPHA                       ; Military: Z = UT;
                                             ;  A:-1; (J not used)
                                             ;  M:-12; N:+1; Y:+12
             / ( ("+" / "-") 4DIGIT )        ; Local differential
                                             ;  hours+min. (HHMM)
```

So you'll need to format your date correct as in

```
utl_smtp.write_data(c, 'Date: ' ||
                 to_char(systimestamp, 'Dy "," DD Mon YYYY HH24:MI:SS TZHTZM',
                     'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') ||
                 utl_tcp.crlf);
```

And here is a quick query to show you the current sys time in every hour offset:

```
with generater as
 (select rownum-13 x from dual connect by level < 28 )
  select x, TO_CHAR(systimestamp at time zone x||':00', 'Dy "," DD Mon YYYY HH24:MI:SS TZHTZM','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH')
 from generater;
```

(FYI, ORA-01874: time zone hour must be between -12 and 14).